# How to keep 4.1 theme & remove TitleBar in Android?

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-theme

When I created new Android application in Eclipse.In its `AndroidManifest.xml` the theme set to application is`android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`& style.xml is as follows.

```
   <resources>
       <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light" />
   </resources>
```

& my screen appears like this.
[image: Image when android:theme="@style/AppTheme" is set.]

I want to remove the TitleBar from app but want to show the theme of Android 4.1's.

For this I tried

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
```

Now my screen appears like this the TitleBar is removed but theme has changed.

[image: Image when android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar is set.]

Please help me to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this instead : `@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar`.

Comment: This is perfect (even a year and a half later).

Answer (score 0):

Try out putting this in your manifest.

> ```
> android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
> ```